My toy poodle only relieves herself with me now
My Toy Poodle is now 6 and she over the last year and a half will ONLY relieve herself outside if I take her. I am home with her all day doing things and take her outside throughout the day. When my husband gets home she is all over him ready to play and happy to see him but if he takes her out to pee she will go outside to sniff around but she will only relieve herself if I am outside with both of them or I take her out myself.
She will literally hold it all day and will only relieve herself when my husband takes her IF I haven't been home all day and she is about to bust, yet she never goes in the house!. Why is it she only relieves herself with me and not my husband?
We have had her since she was 6 weeks old and no potty training issues and she has been just a DREAM of our first little girl, so why the change?

I cannot give you a definite answer because it's impossible for me to read her mind. But you write "I am home with her all day". That automatically makes you her main social contact and primary caregiver. If her personality is very social oriented, she will automatically develop a very strong bond to you. Some examples of this strong bond are: following you around everywhere you go, anxiously waiting in front of the closed door where she cannot follow you (like the bathroom) and only doing things like eating or relieving herself when you're around.
Personally I don't know if these behaviors are plain habit or driven by some kind of anxiety, but irrelevant of the cause, they are hard to change if you stay at home and your husband is absent during work hours.
The best strategy I know is that your husband needs to profusely reward her for relieving herself. The best reward depends on her personality - verbal praise for the social kind, treats for the greedy eaters and her favorite toy for the toy addicted kind. He probably also should take her on walks alone more often and rewards her on these walks for small things, just to establish a habit in your dog that this is normal and good. Some dogs also react positively to play during walks (like retrieving sticks or prey dummies) and the added physical activity stimulates them to relieve themselves.
Your husband should also do basic obedience training with her if he doesn't do that regularly already (the standard "sit", "come here" and whatever commands she knows). Following commands and being rewarded for obedience does strengthen the bond between human and dog. And it also prepares her for the next step:
In combination with that you could establish a new command that means "this is the right time and spot to relieve yourself". You start by saying something like "go potty" every time you are out with her and she starts relieving herself. Do this for a considerable time (like several weeks) until she connects the command with the action. Then you can say the command when you notice her sniffing in her favorite pee spot, but before she actually starts peeing. This should further strengthen the connection between command and action in her mind.
Only one you have the feeling that she understands and follows your command to "go potty" should your husband start using the same command on his walks. This is important because every time she ignores a command, the mental connection between command and action is weakened.

First of all, I love poodles. Second of all, being so smart, they often over-think things, which can lead to anxiety and separation anxiety. If they spend most of their time with you, they might not have learned to easily cope with being alone or being resilient. You also don't mention how well they react with other non-family humans and dogs. I am a pro-dog walker, and have found that regular walks (three minimum per week) are often the best way of socializing a dog, and having them explore as a real dog. It can resolve many issues.
Of course I and any other replier here are only guessing at possible issues and solutions, but I know enough poodles and poodle crosses to know that without exercise and having puzzles to solve, like how to approach a random good dog, can really give them great satisfaction - if they are at the level of being off lead in friendly dog parks already.
I am answering this question, not just to help, or from my experiences alone, but because one of my clients with a schnauzer has lately (over the last year) been having similar issues. Her dog is nearly 9, and didn't have toilet issues before, but since she moved house, and the fact she lives home alone (so she is her dogs main contact and vice versa, there seems to be some parallel.
She has tried taking her dog out before bed, early in the AM when they seemed restless, synthetic pee grass inside as an alternative, but her dog is actually randomly peeing and pooping inside too now. He is the bravest of dogs, inquisitive in the dog park, but at home he is apparently restless and shows signs of anxiety.
He has also begun digging massive holes along the back fence line, and anti-anxiety meds he has tried don't seem to work. Except for getting a good dog behaviorist around, I would guess her dog is not feeling safe at home, and is hearing a lot of wild animals (mostly dogs and possums) that are too far away or high pitched for the owner to hear. under the cover of darkness he has become scared of the 'unknown'.
He hasn't been confronted in his back yard, but as said is highly strung, and shows separation anxiety signs. It is possible how he is verbally being 'told off' through frustration, is only adding to his behavior they wont to eradicate.
So in summary, having more people around, (so you aren't the only one they look to), taking them to off lead dog parks (when they are ready to burn excess mental energy. Working on sorting any potential 'separation anxiety' issues, finding an anti anxiety med that works for them without zonking them out, and finally getting a dog behaviorist are the options I can recommend.
Hope that helps.  You both deserve the best lives !
